# Myframe is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, itemlistener

I am new to the Java programming. I am just doing a program to select the gender using checkbox. but when I run the program I am getting an error as

```
Myframe is not abstract and does not override abstract method itemStateChanged(ItemEvent) in ItemListener
```

The code is as follows

```
import java.awt.event.*;
class Myframe extends Frame implements ItemListener{
    CheckboxGroup cbg;
    Checkbox chkmale,chkfemale;
    Label lblres;

    void init(){
        cbg = new CheckboxGroup();
        chkmale = new Checkbox();
        chkfemale = new Checkbox();
        lblres = new Label();

        add(chkmale); add(chkfemale); add(lblres);

        this.addWindowListener(new MyListner());
        chkmale.addItemListener(this);
        chkfemale.addItemListener(this);
    }
    public void itemstateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent ie){
        if(chkmale.getState() == true){
            lblres.setText("Male");
        }
        else{
            lblres.setText("Female");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so, either make that class abstract, or implement the method. If you really are new in Java, start by learning the base concepts, don't jump into frameworks just yet

Comment: Make an abstract method inside the ItemListener, because you implemented the class.\

Comment: @Francisaskquestion that answer makes no sense at all. there already IS an abstract method in the ItemListener interface, that's the issue

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question, thought it was a custom abstract class

Comment: Typo: `itemstateChanged != itemStateChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply because you're incorrectly implementing the `java.awt.event.ItemListener` interface.
It should be `itemStateChanged` instead of `itemstateChanged`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

class Myframe extends Frame implements ItemListener {
    ...

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        // Your code here.
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `@Override` so that you won't forget that the method is implementing the interface.